# Playa - PHP error after moving server

Tags: playa

I have a site using 2.5.3 .  I've moved this site to a new server and when logged onto the control panel, I get the following error on the front page of the site:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Parameter 3 to Playa_ext::channel_entries_tagdata() expected to be a reference, value given

Filename: libraries/Extensions.php

Line Number: 241
```

I've updated Playa to version 4.5.2 , but the errors are still there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this [bug report thread](https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/18263) - this error arises when you run 2.5.3 on certain PHP versions. Upgrading to at minimum 2.5.4 should fix this. From the [release notes](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/about/changelog.html#version-2-5-4):

> Fixed a bug (#18263) where PHP may claim an object wasn’t passed by reference to an extension hook.

Comment: Hi Derek, thanks for help.  I've updated to 2.5.5 and that looks like it's done the trick.  Thanks again.